# SQL Query for joining equivalent rows summing a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables, *articolo* and *saldo*.

*articolo* is like this:

| id | desc_breve | variante | taglia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 338673 | ANYT229 | 00109 | XL |
| 338674 | ANYT229 | 00109 | XL |
| 338675 | ANYT229 | 00109 | XXL |
| 338711 | MYP506S | 00002 | 56 |
| 338712 | MYP506S | 00002 | 58 |
| 338713 | MYP506S | 00002 | 60 |
| 338714 | MYP506S | 00002 | 60 |
| 338715 | MYP506S | 00002 | 62 |

*saldo* (omitting the primary key *id*) is like this:

| id_articolo | giacenza |
| --- | --- |
| 338673 | 12.0000 |
| 338674 | 13.0000 |
| 338675 | 23.0000 |
| 338711 | 2.0000 |
| 338712 | 5.0000 |
| 338713 | 1.0000 |
| 338714 | 8.0000 |
| 338715 | 8.0000 |

I need to join the two tables from the *id* field in *articolo* and the *id_articolo* field in *saldo* with a query that returns *desc_breve*, *variante*, *taglia* and *giacenza*.

The problem is that some rows in the first table have the same *desc_breve*, *variante* and *taglia*, and in that case I have to join them in a single row and SUM their respective *giacenza* field in the *saldo* table.

Is it possible to do a query for that? I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Please not tag RDBMS that you NOT use.

Comment: Could you please provide the desired output for your sample data

Comment: If you need to consolidate multiple rows into a single one... how do you "sum" the `taglia`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be describing a `join` with `group by`:

```
select a.desc_breve, a.variante, a.taglia, sum(s.giacenza)
from articolo a join
     saldo s
     on s.id_articolo = a.id
group by a.desc_breve, a.variante, a.taglia;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
articolo AS A INNER JOIN saldo AS S ON A.id = S.id_articolo
```

This will give you everything in a single result set.  Now from here it is a little more tricky since to GROUP the results by the A.desc_breve column with a SUM(A or B of some column) you will not be able to include the id_articolo column since that would need to be grouped in some way, either by group contatinating the ids or just ditching them if they are not of use in the output.

```
SELECT tmp.desc_breve, SUM(whatever you are doing)
FROM (query above, include the surrounding brackets) AS tmp
GROUP BY tmp.desc_breve;
```